# Using CAConstraints with NSView layers

Tags: macos, layer, nsview

I want a NSView's sublayer to grow/shrink with the view, so that its frame automatically matches view's bounds without need to explicitly reset it.

Assuming that view's main layer always matches view, I tried the following code:

```
let layer = self.layer!  // It is guaranteed to exist
layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
layer.name = "MainLayer"
let sublayer = CALayer()
sublayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.black

layer.addSublayer(sublayer)

sublayer.addConstraint(CAConstraint.init(attribute: .width, relativeTo: "MainLayer", attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.width))
sublayer.addConstraint(CAConstraint.init(attribute: .height, relativeTo: "MainLayer", attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.height))
```

Guess what: no sublayer is seen, unless its frame is set explicitly.
Tried also constraints in opposite direction: from layer to sublayer - same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the CAConstraintLayerManager in your code:

`layer.layoutManager = CAConstraintLayoutManager()`

see snippet in :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caconstraintlayoutmanager

Comment: Yhank you for the reference. It works great now. In addition to 'width' and 'height'  I had to add constraints for at least  maxX and maxY and also override  makeBackingLayer function in order to get rid of run-time error: "It's illegal to set the layout manager of an AppKit provided layer..."  There is no need to name the main layer, as 'superlayer' always refers to ... guess what. All the best!